# How to use the same fifo for more consumers and producers?

Tags: c, producer-consumer

I created the two producers and two consumers, producer1 sent to consumer1 two integer number and consumer1 print the sum of numbers, and I have another consumer and producer, producer2 sent to consumer2 the path for folder and consumer2 print the all files from directory (ls command from linux). An now I want to merge together this, for example I want as all producers and consumer to use the same message queue.

This is my code for producer1:
//IPC_msgq_send.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSIZE     128

struct msgbuf
{
    long    mtype;
    char    mtext[MAXSIZE];
};

int main() {
    int msqid;
    // int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
    key_t key;
    struct msgbuf sbuf;
    size_t buflen;

    key = ftok(".", 'g');

    //Get the message queue ID for the given key
    if ((msqid = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT | 0666 )) < 0) {
      perror("Could not get message queue\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    printf("MSQID value: %d\n", msqid);
    //Message Type
    sbuf.mtype = 1;
    printf("Enter a path for a folder : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",sbuf.mtext);

    // getchar();

    buflen = strlen(sbuf.mtext) + 1 ;

    if (msgsnd(msqid, &sbuf, buflen, IPC_NOWAIT) < 0)
    {
        printf ("%d, %ld, %s, %d\n", msqid, sbuf.mtype, sbuf.mtext, (int)buflen);
        perror("Could not send message!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Message Sent\n");

    exit(0);
}
```

Consumer1:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSIZE 128

struct msgbuf
{
    long    mtype;
    char    mtext[MAXSIZE];
};
int main() {
  int msqid;
  key_t key;
  struct msgbuf rcvbuffer;
  char pathForPrint[1024] = "";

  // key = 1234;
  key = ftok(".", 'g');

  if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0666)) < 0) {
    perror("Could not get message queue\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("MSQID value: %d\n", msqid);
  //  Receive an answer of message type 1.
  if (msgrcv(msqid, &rcvbuffer, MAXSIZE, 1, 0) < 0) {
    perror("Could not receive message!\n");
    exit(1);
  }

   //printf("%s\n", rcvbuffer.mtext);
  strcat(pathForPrint, "ls ");
  strcat(pathForPrint, rcvbuffer.mtext);
  system(pathForPrint);
 return 0;
}
```

Producer2:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define VECTOR_SIZE 2

struct msgbuf
{
    long    mtype;
    int     vector[VECTOR_SIZE];
};

int main() {
    int msqid;
    // int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
    key_t key;
    struct msgbuf sbuf;
    size_t buflen;
    int i;

    key = ftok(".", 'g');

    //Get the message queue ID for the given key
    if ((msqid = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT | 0666 )) < 0) {
      perror("Could not get message queue\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    printf("MSQID value: %d\n", msqid);
    //Message Type
    sbuf.mtype = 1;
    while(1){
        printf("Enter a message to add to message queue : ");
        for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            scanf("%d",&(sbuf.vector[i]));

            buflen = sizeof(sbuf.vector[i]) + 1 ;
        }

    // getchar();

        if (msgsnd(msqid, &sbuf, buflen, IPC_NOWAIT) < 0)
        {
            printf ("%d, %ld, %d, %d, %d\n", msqid, sbuf.mtype, sbuf.vector[0], sbuf.vector[1], (int)buflen);
            perror("Could not send message!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
            printf("Message Sent\n");

        sleep(3);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Consumer2:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSIZE 128

#define VECTOR_SIZE 2

struct msgbuf
{
    long    mtype;
    int     vector[VECTOR_SIZE];
};
int main() {
    int msqid;
    key_t key;
    struct msgbuf rcvbuffer;

    // key = 1234;
    key = ftok(".", 'g');
    while(1){  
      if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0666)) < 0) {
        perror("Could not get message queue\n");
        exit(1);
      }
      printf("MSQID value: %d\n", msqid);
      //  Receive an answer of message type 1.
      if (msgrcv(msqid, &rcvbuffer, MAXSIZE, 1, 0) < 0) {
        perror("Could not receive message!\n");
        exit(1);
      }

      printf("%d\n", (rcvbuffer.vector[0] + rcvbuffer.vector[1]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For use the same queue is necessary to have the same key, but how to make it ?

Thank you!

Comment: That does not look appropriate to me. A common queue makes sense if any of the consumers can handle any of the messages, which is not the case in your example. What would consumer 2 do if next message in the queue it gets actually is for consumer 1 and vice versa?

Comment: @Aconcagua: that is what the message type is for.

Answer (score 1):

The key is a randomly selectable integer. If you generate the key with `ftok()`, you get the same key as long you refer to the same path and the same id, cf. the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftok.3.html). If you want the same key, it is a bad idea to use a relative path (as you did), since your programs may have different directories. Use an absolute path.

However, please consider the remark of Aconcagua. If you use a common queue, you need different type ids (you use id=1 for both).